# New tag for big-screen chemistry

Tags: discussion

The recent question referencing the [Big Bang Theory TV show](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6350/1573) got me thinking that we need some type of Chemistry in the media tag.  I suggest something like:

[big-screen](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-screen)

[big-screen-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-screen-chemistry)

[hollywood](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood)

[hollywood-chem](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood-chem)

I don't know what the process is of adding new tags, but I am aware from conversations at other *.SE sites that adding tags shouldn't be taken lightly.  Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me. But RT's suggestions seem OK.

Comment: @ManishEarth The nature of chemistry in pop culture I think makes it stand out from a subjective meta tag.  One potential area of concern would be the "Can [insert chemistry] from [Breaking Bad, Big Bang Theory, CSI,...] actually happen" type questions could degenerate into discussions.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2904/4945, https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/309/4945

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to be the dissenter and say if the demand increases for such a tag, we should definitely create it, but with only one question, I'm not sure it's necessary.

However, if there are a few other questions about which I've forgotten that would fit the bill, then by all means, go for it.

Comment: We have 2-3 Derek Lowe questions that would fit the bill. "Things I won't work with" et al.

Comment: So generating tags before a set of questions exists is a cart-before-the-horse scenario?

Comment: @bobthechemist I'm not so vehemently opposed to starting one and seeing if people come up with more questions, I worry (a bit) that something like the well-intentioned `popular-culture` will get abused.  I'm definitely not saying this has to be an edict, just something to think about, though.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose we could turn it into a big crossover event with Movies.SE and get some additional views lol.

Answer (score 2):

What's about 'chemistry-in-the-media' or my personal suggestion 'popular-culture'?