# Can I ask Breaking Bad questions?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I found a question which got my attention, well [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7489/4028), and it didn't called my attention because it was interesting (which it could be) but because a tag that somehow in my eyes is kind of choking to find in a Chemistry Q&A site, the tag [breaking-bad](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-bad) had 2 questions when I read it yesterday, but today it has 3. Is important to note that Chemistry is still in beta. Is a critical time for the folks here, where outside people can and will ask a new question within the scope of the site.

I mention scope because tags reflects what kind of questions can be asked [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com). Remeber that tags are the simple reflection to what a site is and what it aspire to become. When you create a tag, you are telling users after you "hey, you can ask about that here too", since tags needs to describe what is the topic the question is about and if the topic is acceptable within the scope.

I hope you can give a response and keep observant of the tag creation so in the future when the site wants to enforce a determinated scope, the tags doesn't play against yourself.

Comment: I don't think anyone will start asking plot related questions, and if they do, we can take care of it when the time comes.  For better or worse, the show is portraying chemistry concepts which may prompt "popular science" type questions (and some in-depth ones as in the above example).  I don't see it as being problematic for the time being. What would be a welcome addition is if someone established a good solid tag wiki for it defining what sorts of questions might or might not be acceptable.

Comment: @jonsca well, dunno you but users being users, I wouldn't rise my hopes too high. I would rather use everyday-chemistry, or popular-chemistry instead of a tag that might bring confusion latter on. I'm just warning about what *could* happen if the tag is left as is. You know that prevention is the better fix.

Comment: I appreciate your concern.  If the scenario you propose came to fruition, I don't see how retagging the questions, merging tags, or (in the absolute worst case) blacklising the tag itself would be a huge drain on someone's time.  Right now, there are 3 questions.  If it becomes a mishmosh of 10-15 questions that are marginally on topic, we will take notice.

Comment: I'm uneasy about the tag but OK about chem questions from the series. As long as they aren't fantasy chem questions.

Comment: @jonsca while I believe you have your reasons to take that action, remember the broken window problem. Someone will see a tag about some fiction work, they will create their own tag for another fiction work, when you open your eyes you have 100 tags that has little to nothing to do about chemistry. That is my biggest fear, that bad tags promote the creation of more bad tags.

Comment: @Braiam It's important to anticipate these kinds of problems, I agree, but you are strongly underestimating the fact that we (as moderators) are keeping an eye on things.  If it becomes a problem, it will be curbed or dealt with.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213751/how-appropriate-are-question-origin-tags

Answer (score 7):

(Transferred from the comments above for the sake of moving this out of unanswered status)

I don't think anyone will start asking plot related questions, and if they do, we can take care of it when the time comes. For better or worse, the show is portraying chemistry concepts which may prompt "popular science" type questions (and some in-depth ones as in the above example). I don't see it as being problematic for the time being. What would be a welcome addition is if someone established a good solid tag wiki for it defining what sorts of questions might or might not be acceptable.